# Background worker to load a bing maps control

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, windows-phone, panorama-control

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application with a Panorama Page.

This page has two items, first with some text, and second one with a control map. This second one gets too long to load, so I've decided to load it this way:

```
namespace Tested
{
    public partial class DemoDetail : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private bool isFirstNavigateToMap;
        private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
        private Map map;

        public DemoDetail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            map = null;
            isFirstNavigateToMap = true;
            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

            bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
            bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            map = new Map();
        }

        private void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (map != null)
                mapGrid.Children.Add(map);
        }

        private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Panorama panorama = (Panorama)sender;
            PanoramaItem panoramaItem = (PanoramaItem)(panorama.SelectedItem);

            if ((isFirstNavigateToMap) && (panoramaItem.Name.Equals("mapPanoramaItem")))
            {
                isFirstNavigateToMap = false;
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I move to second panorama item, I get this exception on line `map = new Map();`:

```
No se controló System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  Message=Invalid cross-thread access.
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject..ctor(UInt32 nativeTypeIndex, IntPtr constructDO)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject..ctor(UInt32 nativeTypeIndex)
       at System.Windows.UIElement..ctor(UInt32 nKnownTypeIndex)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor(UInt32 nKnownTypeIndex)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor(UInt32 nKnownTypeIndex)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl..ctor()
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapBase..ctor()
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapCore..ctor()
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map..ctor()
       at Demonstration.DemoDetail.bgWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRun(Object argument)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

**How can I create and load a control map asynchronously?**

Comment: at which line are you getting the cross thread operation error?

Comment: On this line: map = new Map(); It's in my question.

Comment: Is Map a UI object? In that case you will have to invoke the action.

Comment: @nawfal Could you please add an answer to my question? It would be easy to me to understand what is an invoke. Thanks.

Comment: do tell me if Map is an UI element or not. Because I have not used windows phone much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{ 
      map = new Map();   
});
```

Anything that has to do with UI will have to be done in the thread that started it, the UI thread. When you are accessing UI from background thread, then you should let the UI thread to act on it by asking UI thread to invoke it from a queue.

PS: There are plenty of similar threads on SO, please do a `cross thread error` search.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. Bing map control is UI object, so it must be created on the UI thread.

Comment: I think I can move to second panorama item and, when this second item is visible I could start creating and showing map control. How can I do this?

Comment: You can create your map normally, but set map Visibility property to Collapsed. In such way, map will not have any impact on the visual tree rendering. Then, when you move to second panorama item, set map visibility property to Visible. I use this trick sometimes to gain better performance when application contains multiple rich visuals.